# How to compare selected files with js

Tags: javascript, file, upload

I'm using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload to upload files. But basicly it uses native javascript *File* interface. And i need to check if user didn't upload same file twice. Problem is that *File* interface does'n allow to access file path.

So how do I compare files with minimum system load?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could track the files that are successfully uploaded in an array, and when a new file is added check if it is already in the array:

```
var uploadedFiles = new Array();

$(inputSelector).fileupload({
  /* your configuration */
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
  /* this is called when a file is added for upload */

  var file = data.files[0];
  console.log('added '+file.name+','+file.type+','+file.size);

  /*
   * check here if a file with the same name, type and size has been 
   * stored in the uploadedFiles array 
   */ 

}).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
  /* this is called when a file has been uploaded successfully */

  var file = data.files[0];
  console.log('uploaded'+file.name+','+file.type+','+file.size);

  uploadedFiles.push(file);

});
```

Comment: So i'll basicaly check 3 attribudes of file. But theese attributes can be same and it'll still be two different files. I can have 2 PDF files with name file.pdf and same size in bytes.

Comment: Same filename and size in bytes, but different content? That is very unlikely. But if you insist you can process the file content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897896/jquery-file-upload-where-is-the-file-data-when-pre-processing-http-blueimp-gi